# How to group data from multiple MySQL queries & order them based on dates in Cypress JS test?

Tags: javascript, mysql, cypress

On my UI, I have a HTML table that displays the following:

```
| COMPANY | MEETING DATE | MEETING TYPE |

| ABC Ltd. | 15-Jul-2011 | Annual       |
| XYZ Inc. | 24-Oct-2008 | Annual       |
```

I am writing a Cypress test to validate the data displayed on this table.

The problem is that the MySQL queries are a bit complex & use several DB tables.

The 1st MySQL query I have below returns each `company.name` which I want to use to validate the first column of the UI table above.

The 2nd MySQL query (that has to use `company.companyId` from the 1st query) returns the `meeting[0].meetingdate` & `meeting[0].type` which I want to use to validate the 2nd & 3rd columnns of the UI table above.

Another thing also, is that the UI table is ordered in descending order based on the Meeting Date.

I'm able to return the company name & the meeting details seperately in each MySQL query, but I don't know how to group them together, & then order those objects based on meeting date.

Here is my latest code:

```
// Query to find companies related to the logged-in user:
cy.task('queryDb',
    `SELECT c.name, c.companyId
    FROM gap.companies c
    JOIN gap.user_companies guc
    ON c.companyId = guc.companyId
    JOIN gap.users users
    ON guc.userId = users.userId
    WHERE users.username = '${Cypress.env('username')}';`).then(companies => {

        companies.forEach(company => {
            // I plan on using company.name to assert on the first column of the UI table
            cy.log('companyId: ' + company.name)
            cy.log('companyId: ' + company.companyId)

            // Query to find each company's latest meeting details:
            cy.task('queryDb',
                `SELECT r.meetingdate, r.meetingtype
                FROM gap.reports r
                WHERE r.reportId IN (
                                    SELECT report_comps.reportId
                                    FROM gap.report_companies report_comps
                                    WHERE report_comps.companyId = (
                                                                    SELECT c.companyId
                                                                    FROM gap.companies c
                                                                    WHERE c.companyId = '${company.companyId}')
                )
                ORDER BY creationdate
                DESC LIMIT 1;`).then(meeting=> {
                    if (meeting[0]?.meetingdate && meeting[0]?.meetingtype) {
                        cy.log(meeting[0].meetingdate)
                        cy.log(meeting[0].meetingtype)
                    } else {
                        cy.log('Details: ' + 'BLANK')
                    }

                })
        })
});
```

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products. Which are you *really* using? `DESC LIMIT 1` suggests MySQL, as T-SQL doesn't use `LIMIT`.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, updated now, it's MySQL

Comment: On a separate note, syntax like `c.companyId = '${company.companyId}'` looks like a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: Cypress is for UI testing. For UI testing you should not query directly the DB, you use JSON files to mimic the AJAX requests and behavior of your UI.

If you want to test mysql they have native tools for that like: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_MYSQLTEST.html

Comment: I'm using the DB as the expected results to validate the UI in an e2e test